# Customize Facebook Newsfeed Message When Someone Likes Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

Does anyone know if it is possible to customize the message that populates in newsfeeds when someone Likes my company's Facebook Page?  We are beginning a charity gig on our Facebook Page next year, and we would prefer the message say "(Person) Liked (Company Name) and donated $5 to (Charity)" rather than "(Person) Liked (Company Name)."

Answer (score 1):

This will only be possible using Open Graph Actions. So you will need to create an app for your fans to use.